# Unable to extract XML Data from SQL Server using bcp

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, bcp

I am trying to extract an xml column value from a sql server table via bcp, but I am facing the below error.

> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]SELECT
>   failed beca use the following SET options have incorrect settings:
>   'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Veri fy that SET options are correct for use with
>   indexed views and/or indexes on com puted columns and/or filtered
>   indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or
>   spatial index operations.

This is the query i am using via bcp

```
select EventLog.payload.value('(/EventData/Pin)[1]', 'varchar(10)') 
as payload_pin 
from usp.EventLog
```

The above query is working in sql server but not via bcp. 
Has anyone encountered such scenario?

Comment: Try either `SET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` or `SET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` before you run the select (in the BCP select command)

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid. You are my Saviour :)

Comment: Oh did it work? Which one was it - ON or OFF? Why don't you post your result as an answer so that anyone else searching for this finds it.

Comment: bcp "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON ;select el.payload.value('(/EventData/Pin)[1]', 'varchar(10)') as pin;" queryout data.txt

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bcp "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON ;select ColumnName.value('(/EventData/Pin)[1]', 'varchar(10)') as pin;" queryout data.txt